# "I thought she will/would go there tomorrow" Why should we use would in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, difference, tense

"I heard (that) it will rain tomorrow"
In this sentence I know we should use will
However
"I thought she will/would go there tomorrow"
Why should we use would and not will in this sentence?
What is the difference between the two sentences?

Comment: Weather (an impersonal force) is different from human beings. **Would** indicates that you don't know 100% for sure if she's going there. If you're not sure about the weather, you'd say "I'd heard that it might rain tomorrow."

Answer (score 1):

Do you currently think she will go there tomorrow?
If so, then "I think she will go there tomorrow".

If you used to think she would go there tomorrow but no longer do (maybe because you have new information) then:
"I thought she would go there tomorrow but ..."

Answer (score 1):

The difference is the first example sentence uses the verb "heard", but the second uses the verb "thought".

Saying you "heard" something in the past implies that it's what you believe *in the present*, so whatever you heard about the future can be stated with normal *future grammar*. On the other hand, saying you "thought" something *in the past* means it's your *past belief*, so you have to state that belief in the *past tense*.

To compare more clearly, let's only switch the first verbs in your example sentences:

"*I **thought** it **would** rain*" and "*I **heard** she **is going** there tomorrow*" are both correct.

"*I thought that she **will** go there tomorrow*" is never correct.